# How to search a range for a matching word within a string?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, search

What I'm trying to do is this:

Cell `A1` contains a sentence. `The dog had black spots all over`

Column `B` contains a range of keywords. Let's say `B7` contains `dog`.

What would be the formula to get `C1` to return `dog` if the string to search was `A1` and the range containing any matching words was in column `B`?

So

1. look at `A1` for the string
2. search column `B` for any matching words
3. output matching word/words to `C1`

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean something like as `=UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B,ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:B,SPLIT(A1," .,-"),0))))`?

Comment: @JohnSUN Please turn your comment to an answer so it can be accepted and help others as well.

Comment: @Kyle Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the description, your data is presented in this way:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | The dog had black spots all over | **Keywords** |
| 2 |  | well |
| 3 |  | over |
| 4 |  | steps |
| 5 |  | him |
| 6 |  | didn't |
| 7 |  | dog |
| 8 |  | that |
| 9 |  | all |
| 10 |  | behind |
| 11 |  | quiet |
| 12 |  | who |
| 13 |  | any |
| 14 |  | could |

First of all, we divide the phrase from **A1** into separate words:

`=SPLIT(A1," .,-")`

*In the second parameter, list all punctuation marks that may occur in the analyzed phrase, add **! ? : ;** - this will allow you to clear individual terms as much as possible.*

As a result of executing the [**SPLIT() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en#null), you will get the following array:

[image: First result]

Now let's find each word from the **Keywords** column using the [**MATCH() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en#null). This function will return the relative position of the word in the array, or an error if there is no such word. We don't need a position, the fact itself is important to us - a word is found or not found. Therefore, we will wrap this function in [**ISNUMBER()**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296?hl=en#null)

`=ArrayFormula(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:B,SPLIT(A1," .,-"),0)))`

For our example data, this would return an array like this:

```
{FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE...}
```

We use this array in the [**FILTER() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en#null) as ***condition1***. And in case there are duplicates in the **Keywords** column, we wrap our entire formula in the [**UNIQUE() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en#null)

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B,ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:B,SPLIT(A1," .,-"),0)) ))`

[image: Result]